# Convert JSON to a class c#

Tags: c#, json

My application receives 2 JSON. One of which is:

```
{
  "topics": {
"test1": {
  "topic": "test1",
  "partitions": {
    "0": {
      "partition": 0,
      "next_offset": 8265537,
      "app_offset": 8265537,
      "stored_offset": 8265537,
      "commited_offset": 8265537,
      "committed_offset": 8265537,
      "eof_offset": 8265537,
      "lo_offset": 8261962,
      "hi_offset": 8265537,
      "consumer_lag": 0
    },
    "1": {
      "partition": 1,
      "next_offset": 9207622,
      "app_offset": 9207622,
      "stored_offset": 9207622,
      "commited_offset": 9207622,
      "committed_offset": 9207622,
      "eof_offset": 9207622,
      "lo_offset": 9203938,
      "hi_offset": 9207622,
      "consumer_lag": 0
    },
    "2": {
      "partition": 2,
      "next_offset": 7954425,
      "app_offset": 7954425,
      "stored_offset": 7954425,
      "commited_offset": 7954425,
      "committed_offset": 7954425,
      "eof_offset": 7954425,
      "lo_offset": 7950785,
      "hi_offset": 7954425,
      "consumer_lag": 0
      }
     }
   }
 }
  }
```

And the other is test2 with "topic" as "test2". And the topic name differentiates both the JSON.

One way I basically converted it into dynamic object and loop through the JSON. 
But I want to create one common class for both JSON to convert it into. My only confusion is how can create a generic class to deserialize both the JSON.

Because right now I am creating two classes like :

```
 public class Root
 {
   public Topics topics { get; set; }
 }

 public class Topics
 {
    public Test1 test1 { get; set; }
 }

 public class Test1
 {
   public string topic { get; set; }
   public Partitions partitions { get; set; }
 }
```

And same way for test2.

Any help?

Comment: if you don't know in advance what the JSON structure is going to be, then you can't specify a concrete type you want to deserialise it to. I'm not sure you can realistically do this. Are the structures of the "test1" and "test2" objects very different?

Comment: Do the "1", "2" and "3" have various differing fields - the last and the first two seem to differ. Is that always the case? Are there always 3, or a varying number, like some kind of Array or List?

Comment: @doctorlove: No fields in Partition will not differ only the Root Topic Name will change either test1 or test2

Comment: Also, have you got any control over the JSON you're receiving? Is it coming from some code you wrote, or can influence? This isn't a brilliant structure - as doctorlove is hinting, it might make more sense for "Partitions" to be an array rather than a list of items with numbered keys. Also if we can see "test2"'s structure, for comparison, maybe we could see a way to merge them into a single type.

Comment: @ADyson: Basically this  JSON we receive from Kafka Statistics and it will in this format only.

Comment: I suppose the other option, if there is a limited possible set of things which "topics" could contain, is simply to list them all e.g. `public class Topics
 {
    public Test1 test1 { get; set; }     public Test2 test2 { get; set; }
 }` and then you will always get one or other of the properties populated. But you haven't told us enough about what all the possible responses could look like, so it's hard to give a definitive answer. We need to know exactly how variable this data could be in reality - what are the limits of this?

Comment: In the posted code, "2" has no "partition" field. You could make a struct for the now partition sub-fields and hold a list of them, surely?

Comment: We would need to know the schema of the JSON you are going to receive to give a proper answer. for example, are the values always `Test1` and `Test2` or will they be random? How many will there be? Why does partition 2 not have a `partition` property etc.

Comment: @DavidG: JSON will either have test1 or test 2 as Topic name. And about partition 2 it will have same properties also. I may have missed that. And one more question do I need to create multiple classes for 0,1 and 2 inside the partition or can we make that also generic? Because the number of partitions can increase

Comment: See my answer for an example of how to handle the partition numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `Dictionary<>` types for keys that will change like the `test1` value and the partition numbers. For example, something like this should work well:

```
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string, Test> Topics { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Partition> Partitions { get; set; }
}

public class Partition
{
    [JsonProperty("partition")]
    public int PartitionNo { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("next_offset")]
    public int NextOffset { get; set; }

    // etc...
}
```

And deserialise with:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(Json);
```

Answer (score 0):

**List Sample:** 
 - JSON object & class object like below:

```
    {
      "topics":[{
        "topic":"test1",
        "partition":{...}
        },{
        "topic":"test2",
        "partition":{...}
       }]
    }


    class Root
    {
        public List<Topics> topics { get; set; }
    }
    class Topics
    {
        public string topic { get; set; }
        public Partitions partitions { get; set; }
    }
```

**Specify Sample:**
 - JSON object & class object like below:

```
    {
      "topics":{
        "test1":{
        "topic":"test1",
        "partition":{...}
        },
        "test2":{
        "topic":"test2",
        "partition":{...}
       }]
    }

    class Root
    {
        public Test topics{ get; set; }
    }
    class Test{
        public Topics test1{get;set;} 
        public Topics test2{get;set;} 
    }
    class Topics
    {
        public string topic { get; set; }
        public Partitions partitions { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: One way to be able to call it into a generic code is to create a [JsonIgnore] or equivalent property that return either test1 or test2 (the one not null).

Comment: @Andy: At one point in time we can have only one Topic. So do we need a list? And in case of 2 properties which property it will set at the time of deserializing since we will have only one topic? And how to deal with multiple partitions. You have created only a Partition class but how can it represent values of partitions 0 to 1 along with its properties like offset?

Comment: @JacobHigs  I misunderstand this question, sorry for that and 
I will be more cautious. And DavidG 's answer is better